# Not able to hit the deployed webservice from browser

Tags: java, spring, cxf

Created a sample wsdl. Generated the Java Objects from the wsdl with CXF framework. Everything is fine and am able to test the service implementation from a local test class.

But when i deploy in Tomcat and hit the url, am not getting all the deployed services.

**Web.xml**

```
        <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
         <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/services/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

**spring.xml**

```
         <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
         <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

         <jaxws:endpoint id="testWS" implementor="#helloWorldService"
                address="/testWS">
         </jaxws:endpoint>

         <bean id="helloWorldService"     class="com.test.ws.service.HelloWorldServiceImpl" />
```

**testing.wsdl**

```
Have included the below snippet as well

         <wsdl:service name="HelloWorldService">
               <wsdl:port name="HelloWorldPort"    binding="tns:HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldPort" />
        </wsdl:port>
    </wsdl:service>
```

**Tested from Test class and it works fine.**

```
      HelloWorldServiceImpl helloWorldService = (HelloWorldServiceImpl)            context.getBean("helloWorldService");
        SayHi hi = new SayHi();
        hi.setText("Webservice Sample");
        helloWorldService.sayHi(hi);

        AdditionInput input = new AdditionInput();
        input.setInput1(10);
        input.setInput2(100);

        System.out.println(" Addition Output : " +     helloWorldService.addtion(input).getResult());
```

But of no help. Please suggest what am i missing here, there should be some minor mistake here.

Comment: what URL are you hitting?

Comment: i tried with the below possible options: http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldPort/services/testWS?wsdl  , http://localhost:8080/sampleproject/services/testWS?wsdl   , http://localhost:8080/sampleproject/HelloWorldPort/services/testWS?wsdl   , but nothing is working out and am not able to see the services in the browser.

Comment: try http://localhost:8080/HelloWorldPort/testWS/services?wsdl

Comment: Sampada, tried the URL, but no help...its not working. :(

Comment: Have you specified a context root for the WAR?

Comment: Yep....  <Context docBase="sampleproject" path="/sampleproject" reloadable="true"/> in my server.xml...                                                                I tried with  localhost:8080/sampleproject/services/testWS?wsdl ,  and tried the below in the wsdl as well                                                      <wsdl:service name="HelloWorldService">
  <wsdl:port name="HelloWorldPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding">
   
   <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/sampleproject/services/testWS" />
  </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how the URL is constructed:

```
http://<server>:<port>/<context-root>/<url-pattern>/<service_name>?wsdl
```

And soap:address location is this:

```
soap:address location="http://<server>:<port>/<context-root>/<url-pattern>/<service_name>.<port_name>"
```

So, in your case, this should be the configuration:

```
<wsdl:service name="HelloWorldService">
         <wsdl:port name="HelloWorldPort" binding="tns:HelloWorldServiceSoapBinding">
            <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/sampleproject/services/HelloWorldService.HelloWorldPort" />
        </wsdl:port>
```

URL:

http://localhost:8080/sampleproject/services/HelloWorldService?wsdl

You can change the `jaxws:endpoint` address to "/".

If you wish to keep it, add it between `url-pattern` and `service_name` at both places.

Comment: Tired all the options you shared here, even replacing my ip address instead of localhost...but nothing is working...fed up here..as everything looks fine, minor thing which am missing...i couldnt figure that out... :(

Comment: i noticed now the below error "HTTP Status 403 - Access Denied" , i think it should be "404 if it is not able to find the service" , am i right? so is any certificate is mandatory for running a service in the local machine also? Long time back i have done similar webswrvice and it worked well, but i had some certificates in my machine for that project...not sure on this.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your answers. The real issue here is, am a newbee to the project ,here the security is not handled in the xmls and i was not aware of the security being handled in the java code, now i have added my service path in the security java file and it is working..... :) Finally Happy...